# MySQL DELETE doesn't work when value has hyphen

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've found that a hyphen in a value in a MySQL DELETE statement from PHP tends to make the thing just... not work. It doesn't fail, but it also doesn't delete the proper rows. Why exactly is this? INSERT works fine, it's just DELETE.

Edit: The particular query I'm running in this case (with the IP removed) is:

```
DELETE FROM ratings WHERE ip=IP_ADDRESS AND video = '-yfOsVrJLGt'
```

This runs successfully when I remove the hyphen.
I've also added that this occurs in PHP, and is seemingly limited to such.

Table structure, as per request:[image]

There are currently no records in it.

Comment: does `UPDATE` works? are you sure you commit your `DELETE` after deleting the row?

Comment: Can you show your table records and structure!

Comment: @BehnamSafari Yes, `UPDATE` works. I'm working with PHP, so there's not really anything to commit.

Comment: Search for -yfOsVrJLG with the s removed,probably the insert got truncated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `video` column length is `varchar(10)`, but passing value contains `11`

```
video = '-yfOsVrJLGs'
```

Comment: I feel quite silly now. I suppose it failed, then, because the last character was cut off. I just assumed it was the hyphen, since when I removed it, it worked. :P

Answer (score 1):

check your `video` length.`varchar(10)` but `-yfOsVrJLGs` contain 11 character.So try to give correct input

```
DELETE FROM ratings WHERE ip=IP_ADDRESS AND video = 'yfOsVrJLGs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, but easily to make the mistake.

Your length of the column is varchar(10) and but needs to be varchar(11) as there are 11 characters. `video = '-yfOsVrJLGs'`